# Prove 3 vectors are collinear

Tags: vectors, affine-geometry

I am asked to prove A(2,4), B(8,6), C(11,7) are collinear using vectors.

I can work AB by subtracting A from B and BC by subtracting B from C in vector form.

I can say that BC = 2AB.

But I don't understand why this proves they are collinear.

Comment: Your conclusion $BC =2 AB$ is not correct. Please see my answer.

Comment: Also, your title is not really right. You're not proving three vectors, are collinear, you're proving three points are collinear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=(2,4), \; B=(8,6), \; C=(11,7)$, then
$$
\vec{AB} = B - A = (6,2) \quad ; \quad
\vec{BC} = C - B = (3,1)
$$
So $\vec{AB} = 2 \vec{BC}$, which is different from your conclusion.

Anyway, this says that $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ are parallel, since one is just a multiple of the other. So, to get from $B$ to $C$, you go in the same direction you went to get from $A$ to $B$ (no turn is required). This means that $A$, $B$, $C$ must all lie on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Because now you can parametrice:

$$A=B-BA$$

$$B=B$$

$$C=B-BC=B+\frac12 BA$$

Now can you see that they are on one line?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to check this is by slopes: three points on a plane are collinear if and only if the slopes between any two of them are equal, and here you have

$$m_{AB}=m_{AC}=m_{BC}=\frac13$$

Answer (score 0):

They're indeed colinear.

To see this, use:

> **Proposition 0.** Given some points $A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, these points are colinear iff the span of $\{A_1-A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}-A_0\}$ has dimension at most $1$.

So begin by computing $B-A$ and $C-A$:

$$B-A = (6,2), \qquad C-A = (9,3)$$

Now you can use linear algebra to find out the dimension of the span of the above two vectors; in fact, it is obviously just $1$, since they're scalar multiples of each other. Hence the original triple is indeed colinear.

There's higher dimension versions, of course. For example:

> **Proposition 1.** Given some points $A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, these points are *coplanar* iff the span of $\{A_1-A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}-A_0\}$ has dimension at most $2$.

The take-home message is that we can often answer questions about affine geometry by first subtracting by an appropriate vector so that now we're just doing linear algebra.

Comment: Since the OP is doing elementary vector arithmetic, he (or she) probably doesn't know what "affine space" or "affine dimension" mean.

Comment: @bubba, well I wanted to explain the underlying idea, which is that you can answer questions about affine geometry by first subtracting by an appropriate vector so that you're now dealing with vector geometry. If this is all going over the OP's head, he/she can always just rely on your answer which "cuts straight to the chase" so to speak. But we live in the information age, and as always my hope is that the OP will Google unfamiliar terms and struggle with them until they're understood.

Answer (score -1):

Two vectors are colinears (and so your the end points) if, and only if there one is multiple of other.